# Question about homomorphism of groups

Tags: group-theory, functions

$G,H$ are groups, $\varphi:G\to H$ is homomorphism.
How do I prove: $$\ker\varphi=\left\{{e_G}\right\} \Leftrightarrow \varphi\;\text{is injective} $$

I have problem with $\Rightarrow$ direction.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)$, we are going to prove that this implies $x=y$, given that $\ker\varphi = \{e_G\}$.

**Hint:** *What* can you say about $\left(\varphi(y)\right)^{-1}=?$ Try multiplying by it on both sides.

Comment: That: $\left(\varphi(y)\right)^{-1}=\left(\varphi(x)\right)^{-1}?$
But how this helps me that $\ker\varphi = \{e_G\}$?
Thank you so much!

Comment: I think I got it! Tell me if I'm right:

At the and I should get: $e_H=e_H$ right?

Comment: @YoavFridman Well, you shouldn't get that I think. Tell me what you did exactly.

Comment: $\varphi(x)\cdot \varphi(y)^{-1}=\varphi(y)\cdot \varphi(y)^{-1}$. Then: $\varphi(x)\cdot \varphi(y)^{-1}=e_H$. I'm at right way?
$\varphi(x\cdot y^{-1})=\varphi(e_G)=e_H.$

Comment: @YoavFridman Oh, good, you used that $\varphi(y^{-1}) = \varphi(y)^{-1}$. So you get that $xy^{-1} \in \ker \varphi$, what does that tell you now? Seems good.

Comment: But I don't need to prove other thing about the kernel?

Comment: @YoavFridman What do you mean? You are given that $\ker \varphi = \{e_G\}$ in this case.

Comment: That if $\ker\varphi$ has more then one element it will be true also, I'm right?

Comment: @YoavFridman No, it won't be true. $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)$ is equivalent to $x\cdot y^{-1}\in \ker \varphi$. However, if $e_G\neq g\in \ker \varphi$, we may pick $x = g y$ (fix $y$ first), and these two will satisfy $\varphi(x)=\varphi(y)$, but $x\neq y$.